# Git push error in localhost

Tags: git, push

Hello I have worked on a project and now I want to push my code to the local git repo, I have pushed the code or changes couple of times without any error but today when I give the command. From my Linux operating system ubuntu

```
 git push origin develop
```

I get the following error

```
Connection closed by ::1
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

This is information about my git config

```
git config --list
alias.l=log --pretty=oneline -n 20 --graph
alias.s=status -s
alias.d=diff --patch-with-stat
alias.p=!git pull; git submodule foreach git pull origin master
alias.c=clone --recursive
alias.ca=!git add -A && git commit -av
alias.go=checkout -B
alias.tags=tag -l
alias.branches=branch -a
alias.remotes=remote -v
alias.credit=!f() { git commit --amend --author "$1 <$2>" -C HEAD; }; f
alias.reb=!r() { git rebase -i HEAD~$1; }; r
alias.undopush=push -f origin HEAD^:master
apply.whitespace=fix
core.excludesfile=~/.gitignore
core.attributesfile=~/.gitattributes
core.whitespace=space-before-tab,indent-with-non-tab,trailing-space
core.autocrlf=input
core.editor=vi
color.ui=auto
color.branch.current=yellow reverse
color.branch.local=yellow
color.branch.remote=green
color.diff.meta=yellow bold
color.diff.frag=magenta bold
color.diff.old=red bold
color.diff.new=green bold
color.status.added=yellow
color.status.changed=green
color.status.untracked=cyan
merge.log=true
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
url.git@github.com:.insteadof=gh:
url.git@github.com:.pushinsteadof=github:
url.git@github.com:.pushinsteadof=git://github.com/
url.git://github.com/.insteadof=github:
url.git@gist.github.com:.insteadof=gst:
url.git@gist.github.com:.pushinsteadof=gist:
url.git@gist.github.com:.pushinsteadof=git://gist.github.com/
url.git://gist.github.com/.insteadof=gist:
user.name=Pradeep Rajvanshi
user.email=pradeep@gsmicrosystems.com
github.user=username
github.token=0123456789yourf0123456789token
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=git@localhost:lms.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: I am on linux operating system - ubuntu

Comment: perhaps, you have too many concurrent connections . pls try this `/etc/init.d/sshd restart` in your terminal, then push again.

Comment: when i enter this command                                               /etc/init.d/sshd restart
I get  bash: /etc/init.d/sshd: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Your `origin` remote is set as ssh access on your local machine, which apparently has no `ssh` daemon running. If you want to push to your local repository (why would you do that?) you can do it without ssh, by setting the remote to point directly to your local filesystem.

Comment: I use ssh to commit code to remote online server, but that is totally a different project.

Comment: Your config says `remote.origin.url=git@localhost:lms.git`. This is where it tries to connect when you do `git push origin`.